# Windows UWP BluetoothLEDevice reconnect

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use `BluetoothLEDevice` in a Desktop app without pairing, according to the [Microsoft videos and source codes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/btblog/2017/08/21/bluetooth-le-explorer-code-is-open-source-now/). I subscribe to notify a characteristics and receive it's values, so far so good.

However, if the device goes off/on or is to out of signal for a moment, then it's `ConnectionStatus` is `Disconnected` and does not reconnect again (does not change to `Connected`). How to reconnect device if it's signal is within the range again?

The only way which come to my mind it to keep `DeviceWatcher` running and listen to the `Added` event. Or may it be done in a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no other way. The [`DeviceWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher) is responsible of the devices detection. You will have to monitor the `DeviceAdded` event to redetect your device.

According to the documentation, you should monitor all the events to keep receiving added notification after the initial enumeration.

> An app must subscribe to all of the added, removed, and updated events
>   to be notified when there are device additions, removals or updates.
>   If an app handles only the added event, it will not receive an update
>   if a device is added to the system after the initial device
>   enumeration completes.

Comment: Problem is, that `DeviceWatcher.Removed` is fired after the `BluetoothLEDevice` is created and connected. So, if I need to show a connection status to the user, I have put together information from `DeviceWatcher` and `BluetoothLEDevice.ConnectionStatusChanged` event. Microsoft, why oh why so complicated API for us?